# insertion sort algorithm output error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

i am having the below code converted from C to Obj-C the C code lines are commented below and replaced by Obj-C , but i have a problem in the results the sort is not working properly here is the results after the code if anybody can assist plz

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray  *iarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:garr];
    int n = [iarray count]  ;
    NSLog(@"%@",iarray);

    int i,j,x;

     for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)  

     {  
     j=i;  

     //x=a[i]; 
    x=[[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i]intValue];    

     //while(a[j-1]>x && j>0)  
     while (j>0 &&[[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1]intValue] >x)


     {  

     //a[j]=a[j-1];
    [iarray replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [iarray objectAtIndex: (j-1)]];
     j=j-1;  
     }  

    // a[j]=x;  
    [[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j]intValue] == x; 

     }
    NSLog(@"%@",iarray);
}
```

before sort

```
[Session started at 2012-09-12 02:13:43 +0300.]
2012-09-12 02:13:49.127 sort_alg[1748:207] (
43,
18,
15,
135,
37,
81,
157,
166,
117,
110
```

)

```
and after sort
2012-09-12 02:13:49.130 sort_alg[1748:207] (
43,
43,
43,
43,
135,
135,
135,
135,
157,
166
```

)

Comment: You know, you could have just used plain old C arrays and saved yourself a lot of pain.

Comment: Read the spec for NSMutableArray.  What you need to know is in there.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't doing what you think it is doing:

```
[[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j]intValue] == x;
```

It is getting the intValue of the object at index `j` and then comparing to `x`, and nothing is done with the result.

You should read the documentation for `NSArray` and use the built in sorting method(s).

Comment: thanks but i need to use the algorithm itself and not the built in methods i need this to measure values thanks for ur help coudl u kidly advise on the code thanks

Comment: Modify the code to insert the correct value at the index you need.  That should be straightforward.   What are you measuring? If the answer is "difference in speed between Objective-C and C", then this is *completely the wrong way to do it*.

Answer (score 2):

To set (replace) an element of the array you first do this:

```
//a[j]=a[j-1];
[iarray replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [iarray objectAtIndex: (j-1)]];
```

and then for some reason when you next wish to do something similar you try:

```
// a[j]=x;  
[[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j]intValue] == x;
```

Did you add the `==` to get rid of a compiler error?

The first way is correct - you need to call a method to set (replace) an element in your array.

Now you know the answer...

Comment: when i use the new one  [iarray replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [iarray objectAtIndex: (x)]]; i get *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 111 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

Comment: @OracleOracle - well now you have an algorithmic error. You need to step through the code (use the debugger or `NSLog`) to figure out how `j` ends up with the value `111`.